# How to avoid hitting all retryable topics for fatal-by-default exceptions?

Tags: spring-kafka

My team is writing a service that leverages the retryable topics mechanism offered by Spring Kafka (version 2.8.2). Here is a subset of the configuration:

```java
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, UploadMessage> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
            this.springProperties.buildConsumerProperties(),
            new StringDeserializer(),
            new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(new KafkaMessageDeserializer()));
}

@Bean
public RetryTopicConfiguration retryTopicConfiguration(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate) {
    final var retry = this.applicationProperties.retry();

    return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder.newInstance()
            .doNotAutoCreateRetryTopics()
            .suffixTopicsWithIndexValues()
            .maxAttempts(retry.attempts())
            .exponentialBackoff(retry.initialDelay(), retry.multiplier(), retry.maxDelay())
            .dltHandlerMethod(DeadLetterTopicProcessor.ENDPOINT_HANDLER_METHOD)
            .create(kafkaTemplate);
}
```

`KafkaMessageDeserializer` is a custom deserialiser that decodes protobuf-encoded messages and may throw a `SerializationException` in case of a failure. This exception is correctly captured and transformed into a `DeserializationException` by Spring Kafka. What I find a bit confusing is that the intercepted poison pill message then hits all of the retry topics before eventually reaching the dead letter one. Obviously it fails with exactly the same error at every step.

I know that [`RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder::notRetryOn`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.2/api/org/springframework/kafka/retrytopic/RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder.html#notRetryOn(java.lang.Class)) may be used to skip the retry attempts for particular exception types, but what if I want to use exactly the same list of exceptions as in [`ExceptionClassifier::configureDefaultClassifier`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/abe1209c2e72eaf15aab7ef4db94465892d894c6/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ExceptionClassifier.java#L47-L56)? Is there a way to programmatically access this information without basically duplicating the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a good suggestion; it probably should be the default behavior (or at least optionally).

Please open a feature request on GitHub.

There is a, somewhat, related discussion here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/discussions/2101

Comment: Thank you Gary, the feature request may be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/2113).